# How to call templated type with

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to create a template function that has two different implementations based on a template argument. While the first one is specific for I/O manipulators and the second one is for any general case.

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same<decltype(std::setw), T>::value>::type
foo(T& t){
        cout << "enabled" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T& t){
        cout << "Normal" << std::endl;
}

template <typename... Ts>
void foohelper(Ts... t){
        foo(t...);
}
int main(){
        foohelper(std::setprecision(3)); // It should print enabled, but printing Normal
}
```

Currently it is not doing what I am trying to implement. How can I fix it?

Comment: std::set and std::setprecision are not the same type (also std::setprecision(3) is not the same type as std::setprecision) maybe if you elaborate on the problem more, we can give you an answer!

Comment: Yes, I meant std::setw. They are actually different, see the source code here http://cs.brown.edu/~jwicks/libstdc++/html_user/iomanip-source.html They return a struct, but each struct has a different name!

Try this to verify `std::cout << typeid(decltype(std::setw)).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(decltype(std::setprecision)).name() << std::endl;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `enable_if` - just specialise the template below the main definition of `template foo`.

```
template <>
void foo<decltype(std::setw(0))>(decltype(std::setw(0))& t)
{
        cout << "enabled" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks It works, not I don't understand why I have to keep the definition below main?

Comment: That look good, but is specialization can be replaced by simple overloading in this case?

Comment: @AAA: poor wording on my part - not below the function `main()`, but below the main definition *of the template*, i.e. below `template <typename T>
void foo(T & t) ...`.  The template should be seen before the specialisations.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: for this particular call, yes, but say a function `template <typename T> f` contains code to get a pointer to the function a la `auto p = &foo<T>;`, it misses the overload; not often an actual problem though.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of these functions are *unspecified*. That means you can't use `type_traits` to compare them. As an example, here's `libcxx`:

```
// Definitions omitted
T2 setiosflags (ios_base::fmtflags mask);
T3 setbase(int base);
template<charT> T4 setfill(charT c);
T5 setprecision(int n);
T6 setw(int n);
```

`T5`, `T6`, etc. refer to `__imo_t4` etc., an internal structure that does the actual work of the manipulator. Since they all have different return types, the functions have different types. Hence they'll all be different.

Comment: You can use unspecified types. A great example of that is the return type of `std::bind`

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot How is `std::bind` related to comparing `std::setw` to `std::setprecision`?

Comment: The downvotes are quite sad. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37177827/6323422) doesn't even compile and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37178008/6323422) doesn't address the general case.

Comment: You told that since the return type of these function is unspecified, you can't use them with type_traits to compare them. That's not true, `std::bind` and lambdas both have unspecified types and I commonly use them in type traits and template parameters. I even use the types by calling their `operaror()`. Stating that you can't use them in type traits because their type is unspecified is not true.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: lambda and unspecified returned type of `std::bind` should have some interface as `operator()`, using the unspecified type as this for traits lead to unspecified traits. `T2` and `T3` might be equal type or not, so specialization for one might also apply to the other, and specialize both might compile or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SFINAE by comparing the return type of the function `std::setprecision`. Since the return type is unspecified, you will need `decltype` and `std::declval`.

Here's the solution:

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(std::setprecision(std::declval<int>())), typename std::decay<T>::type>::value, int>::type = 0>
void foo(T&& t) {
    cout << "enabled" << std::endl;
}
```

Here I changed `T&` to `T&&` so it accept any kind of reference. That remove the use of your `foohelper`.

Furthermore, is the type comparison, I decay the type `T`, since the comparison won't work if one of the type is a reference type, because `T&` is not the same as `T`. The use of `std::decay` will effectively remove the reference.

Notice that I moved the SFINAE construct inside the template declaration. This is to keep SFINAE away from the return type. The use of non type template parameter defaulted to `0` won't affect the use of the function and will ensure that no one can effectively bypass the SFINAE check.

Edit:

You can replace `std::declval<int>()` with `0` in your case. I was just willing to show how you can use this tool to replace actual value. There are a lot of cases where you can't have values.

Comment: Many thanks. But I have got to use foohelper, this is the way my application is written.